# Shared memory in pool of processes

Tags: python, multiprocessing, shared-memory

I'm trying to share memory between 4 processes but I it is not working for me, I would like to get help with my problem.

Take a look at the logic of the flow:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, Value
from time import sleep

def work(process):
    if process == 'A':
        sleep(secs=2)     # Processing task A
        a = True          # Marking a shared byte of completed task
    if process == 'B':
        sleep(secs=1)     # Starting processing task B
        while a is False: # Waiting until task A will complete
            pass
        sleep(secs=5)     # Continuing processing task B
        b = True          # Marking a shared byte of completed task
    if process == 'C':
        sleep(secs=7)     # Processing task C
    if process == 'D':
        sleep(secs=1)     # Starting processing task D
        while b is False: # Waiting until task B will complete
            pass
        sleep(secs=4)     # Continuing processing task D

def main():
    a = Value('b', False)
    b = Value('b', False)

    with Pool(processes=4) as pool:
        pool.map(func=work, iterable=('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I can't share the values `a` and `b`, how should I do that?

Thank a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, function `sleep` does *not* take a keyword `secs=` parameter. Second, you need to pass values `a` and `b` to your function `work` as arguments. Third, you need to set and test the `value` attribute of you `Value` instances. Fourth, since you are passing these arguments to pool processes, you should get the `Value` instances from a `SyncManager` instance as shown below.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager
from time import sleep
from functools import partial

def work(a, b, process):
    if process == 'A':
        sleep(2)     # Processing task A
        print('A is marking a True')
        a.value = True          # Marking a shared byte of completed task
    elif process == 'B':
        sleep(1)     # Starting processing task B
        while a.value is False: # Waiting until task A will complete
            pass
        sleep(5)     # Continuing processing task B
        print('B is marking b True')
        b.value = True          # Marking a shared byte of completed task
    elif process == 'C':
        sleep(7)     # Processing task C
    elif process == 'D':
        sleep(1)     # Starting processing task D
        while b.value is False: # Waiting until task B will complete
            pass
        print('D has now found b to be True')
        sleep(4)     # Continuing processing task D

def main():
    manager = Manager()
    a = manager.Value('b', False)
    b = manager.Value('b', False)

    with Pool(processes=4) as pool:
        pool.map(func=partial(work, a, b), iterable=('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Prints:

```
A is marking a True
B is marking b True
D has now found b to be True
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Queue (multiprocessing.Queue() ) to pass messages back and forth.

See this link https://pymotw.com/2/multiprocessing/communication.html